# get all the comments posted on MR and its commits inside it in 1/minimum requests

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

Best way to get all the comments/notes posted on MR and commits inside it in the least number of requests 
If we can Do it in One request it will be better

- For one particular MR we have to do it in a two-step process
- step 1: find all the commits in an MR
- step 2 : get all the messages in every commit

For these two steps, we will be making N-number of requests for an MR with N-number of commits to Gitlab.
I am using gitlab-api https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/notes.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post.

Comment: thanks @Fejs added more info

Comment: I think what you're looking for is this: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/notes.html#list-all-merge-request-notes
This lists all notes (comments) inside a given MR. replace step 2 with that request and the whole thing can be done in 2 steps. It would be helpful to see exactly what requests you're making. From what I understand, you're getting all commits, then foreach commit, you're getting their comments. My suggestion supposedly gets ALL notes (comments) within an MR. Hope this helps.

Comment: I currently doing what you wrote but I was still trying to find a way where i can do the same thing in just one API call

Comment: Well I'm not sure I understand then. Wouldn't you just make 2 requests - 1 for all commits, 1 for all notes -  as supposed to N resquests? (N being the number of commits + 1 for the request for all commits). I don't think there's is yet a way to do it all in 1 request, but only 2 doesn't seem so bad.